# Rails ActionController::Live without restart server on developpement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, server-sent-events

I'm using SSE (Server Sent Event) in rails with the ActionController::Live of rails 4.

It's working fine. But in developpement, I have to defined my configuration like this :

```
Rails.application.configure do

   config.cache_classes = true
   config.eager_load = true
```

I have to restart the puma server each time I do a modification.

**Is there a way to do that without restart ?**

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration of `config.cache_classes = true` explicitly disables hot-reloading of classes when they change. You'll have to set that to false in development to avoid server restarts between changes.

Comment: yes, I know. But all the tutorials that I followed need this params at true. If false is set, the app is blocked https://www.sitepoint.com/mini-chat-rails-server-sent-events/